# Would Egale's recommendations for law reform make anal sex legal at any age in Canada?

Tags: law, sexuality, canada

[LifeSiteNews](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/trudeau-plans-will-allow-sex-anytime-any-place-anywhere-with-anyone-critic) claims recommendations made by [Egale](https://egale.ca), a Canadian LGBT advocacy organization, on changing laws would allow anal sex 'anytime, any place, with anyone'.

Specifically, it claims that the age of consent for anal sex will be completely removed:

> Landolt stressed that because other sections of the Criminal Code do not legislate on anal intercourse, a repeal of Section 159 will mean, in effect, that “there’s no age of consent” for anal sex.
>
> “The point is, consent is under Section 150, and it must be age 16 and above,” she said, “but it does not include anal intercourse as such.”

I'd like to know about the veracity of the claim. Would that mean that anal sex would be allowed with, for example, a 5 year old child?

Comment: Worth reading https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/life-site-news/ - they rate the site Extreme Right Bias. It's not an answer to your question, but gives good reasons why you should not read too much into one of their articles. "They may utilize strong loaded words (wording that attempts to influence an audience by using appeal to emotion or stereotypes), publish misleading reports and omit reporting of information that may damage conservative causes. "

Comment: What a bizarre claim. See e.g. Section [151](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-151.html), [152](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-152.html), [153](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-153.html), [153.1](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-153.1.html), [173](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-173.html), [174](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-174.html)...

Comment: @ff524 Thanks for those links, anyway this only makes the claim less plausible, maybe implementing those recommendations would cause to reform those sections, I think the only way to test the veracity would be to know which exact recommendations the article is talking about and if there's some proof that he's planning to implement them.

Comment: My claim is about what the title is describing, about being able to have anal sex as described due to that supposed recommendations and about Justin Trudeau planning to implement them, you can ignore the rest of the article if you want. You are right in what you are saying, but that this part is wrong doesn't mean that those recommendations don't exist and that Justin Trudeau wouldn't be planning to implement them in the case they exist, although the fact that this part is wrong makes the initial claim less plausible.

Comment: Because what you are describing are the words of Gwen Landolt describing something that is false, but this doesn't change the fact of that supposed recommendations and supposed Justin Trudeau plans about them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as worded, it is asking about the motivations of an individual, which we can't show with empirical evidence. I think there might be a better version of the question, which we should sort out before re-opening.

Comment: There are many claims here and they are getting confused. When we untangle them, we might have a good question. "Any time, any place with anyone" is hyperbole, not a real claim. No-one believes it will be legal to conduct any sexual acts in the street. That should be removed from the question as a distraction. What Trudeau is thinking is off-topic. There is a clear claim "Implementing Egale's recommendations, including removing Criminal Code Section 159, will remove the age of consent for anal sex in Canada." Ask that, but consider if Law.SE is a better site.

Comment: @Oddthinking Lianne Laurence and the people at lifesitenews actually do believe that (or at least purport to do). It's in the later section of the article which is about the bawdy house laws, and then again at the end.

Comment: We still have two different claims here, which I think should be in two different questions, so they can be answered separately. (1) Egale's recommendations will remove the age of consent for anal sex in Canada. (2) Egale's recommendations will prevent any control over sex in public. I believe the "anyone, anytime, anywhere" is hyperbole, not a serious claim. If you can show someone believes it to be true, we should address it.

Comment: A brief look at Sections 210 and 211 show that they are unrelated to sex in public. They are about brothels.

Comment: @Oddthinking Those are different claims, but I think that they could well be grouped together as they are related and concern the overall claim. What I think is a different claim is that Trudeau is actually planning to implement these recommendations. The article is from 2016, and I couldn't find any development since then (or anyone else confirming that Trudeau had planned implementing this). There is also the implied claim that Egale actually recommended these changes.

Comment: @Oddthinking According to the [Egale report](https://egale.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FINAL_REPORT_EGALE.pdf), 210 and 211 were not just applied to brothels, but were used to oppress the LGBT community (by applying it to gay clubs, bathhouses, and private homes). Egale also recommends to apply obsenity regulations equaly in the same chapter. "public sex" still seems like a stretch, but that is probably why OP has doubts in the claim.

Comment: I've deliberately avoided the impossible question of what Trudeau (in his head) was planning, so the question should be about what the recommendations were. I am happy for "repealing Section 159 implies Public Sex is legal" to be asked, but it has a different answer to "Egale recommendations imply no age of consent" so it should be in a separate question. I would ask the first of those questions myself, but I would rather the rep went to the OP than me.

Comment: @Oddthinking OK, fair point. I removed the reference to Trudeau completely, I don't think it's relevant to the claim then (it's also a bit misleading; the source LifeSiteNews used says that Trudeau does not confirm or deny the story, and that they are 'carefully reviewing' the issue, ie there are no actual plans (yet)).

Answer (score 21):

**NO**, Egale is not calling for such changes to the law.

The LifeSiteNews article links to the [Egale final report](https://egale.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FINAL_REPORT_EGALE.pdf).

After some discussion, the recommendations appear on page 43.

> TOWARD CONSENSUAL PARITY
>
> 1. Repeal the ban on anal intercourse and **institute a uniform age of consent**.
> 2. Add new provisions to S.490.012 that provide:
>
>    - Judges must consider the consent and relative age of victim and
>        accused when issuing an order.
>    - Judges must not issue an order if the conduct clearly falls within the legal standards of heterosexual sexual conduct at the time.

Throughout the document this call is repeated, and on page 64 it is expanded upon:

> We wish to be very clear up front: Egale does not condone
>   pedophilia. Historically, the general age of consent has been
>   14 years of age. We agree that allegations of historic same sex
>   sexual activities with persons under 14 years of age should
>   be prosecuted. We are concerned that no double standard be
>   applied, namely that the age of consent not be higher for incidents
>   involving two persons of the same sex.
>
> For the same reasons of principle, we agree that the general
>   rules regarding actual consent should apply equally to same sex
>   behaviour as opposite sex behaviour.
>
> Canada now operates under a nuanced regime where the
>   appropriate age of consent varies from 12 to 18, depending on
>   the circumstances. It is clear that the philosophy behind the
>   current rules involves three general principles: (a) the ordinary
>   age of consent should be sixteen, (b) persons between 12 and 16
>   should not have their consensual sexual behaviour criminalized
>   if their sexual partners are of a similar age, and (c) to protect
>   teenagers from abuse by persons in positions of authority, in
>   those special circumstances, an increased age of consent of 18 is
>   appropriate. Provided these rules are applied equally to opposite 
>   sex behaviour and same sex behaviour, Egale does not quarrel
>   with these principles and rules.